# PHP How to add all array elements to another array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to add all array elements to another array as elements
Here is my codes

```
<pre>
$resultBasedBuild = array();

$data = {0.225, 0.132, 0.114};
$index = 0;

foreach ($data as $singleData) {
   $resultBasedData[] = array(
       'name' => 'my name'      
      ,'data' => array(array($index, $singleData)) 
   );       
}
$result = json_encode($resultBasedData);
</pre>
```

The expected output would be

```
     [{"name":"20140722.1304","data":[[0,0.225],[0,0.132],[0,0.114]]}]
```

Thank you for your help.

I sorted this problem using one more array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = [0.225, 0.132, 0.114];

$result = json_encode(['name' => 'my name', 'data' => array_map(function ($item)
{
    return [0, $item];

}, $data)]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but the output is not what I expected.